# Making click work only on parent item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have footer with some content inside. ANd i made my footer show\hide on click. But now if i click on any item inside footer(i have navbar there) my footer reacting on show\hide aswell. How do i make only parent(footer) to react on clicks, and none of child elements? I'm using jquery mobile.
Here is my code:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-id="main_footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" data-visible-on-page-show="false" data-tap-toggle="false" >


                <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="menu-item-home" data-icon="custom" href="index.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">&nbsp;</a></li>
                        <li><a id="menu-item-near-me" data-icon="custom" href="near-me.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
                        <li><a id="menu-item-rewards" data-icon="custom" href="rewards.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
                        <li><a id="menu-item-invite" data-icon="custom" href="invite.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
                        <li><a id="menu-item-profile" data-icon="custom" href="profile.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div>
            <!-- /footer -->
        </div>
```

And JS

```
$("#index").live('pagecreate', function() {
            $("[data-role='footer']").live("click", function() {
            if ($("[data-role='footer']").hasClass('ui-fixed-hidden'))
            {
                $("[data-role='footer']").removeClass('ui-fixed-hidden');
            }
            else
            {
                $("[data-role='footer']").addClass('ui-fixed-hidden');
            }

                });
        });
```

TLDR; 
I want to make links inside my footer to work, but not trigger footer to show\hide while click on link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add

```
 $(document).on("click", "[data-role='footer'] li", function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Note that I used `on` instead of `live`, which is deprecated. Note also that jQuery has a useful [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function. So I'd suggest you replace your existing code with

```
$("#index").live('pagecreate', function() {
     $(document).on("click", "[data-role='footer'] li", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
     });
     $(document).on("click", "[data-role='footer']", function() {
        $("[data-role='footer']").toggleClass('ui-fixed-hidden');
     });
});
```

Comment: where you want, it doesn't really matter. Just not in one of your existing functions.

Comment: THe problem is when i click on link that inside footer, it doesnt works. Any ideas how to make only them work, withouht trigger footer to show\hide?

Comment: I hadn't seen at first you wanted to make the link work. See edited answer.

Comment: @sannySin I think you have to add `location.href = [the address of the clicked link]` below `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: i have 5 links, whihc of those do i have to add?
PS: all links are being loaded via ajax(because of jquery mobile)

Comment: @sannySin I edited to propose the code to replace your whole existing code.

Comment: This worked, but for now it reloads whole page, without ajax, which is not good for my projects. Any other ideas how to make this work?

Comment: You have a link `href="index.html"`. Of course it reloads the whole page. If you want different links, that's a very different question.

Answer (score 1):

For a variety of reasons, you shouldn't actually use `.live`, but replace it with `.on`.  Anyway, I think this will work:

```
... 'click', function (e) {
   if ($(e.target).not("[data-role=footer]")) {
      e.stopPropagation();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work...i suggest u to use `on` instead on `live`...

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-role='footer']", function(e) {
    if(e.target != this){
      return;
    }

    if ($("[data-role='footer']").hasClass('ui-fixed-hidden'))
    {
       $("[data-role='footer']").removeClass('ui-fixed-hidden');
    }
    else
    {
        $("[data-role='footer']").addClass('ui-fixed-hidden');
    }

 });
```

Comment: it still triggers my footer if i click on link inside navbar

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that , the link in the footer not works. The easiest solution for this, is bind a `click` event to the link inside your footer and use either `$.mobile.changePage()` or `window.location()` method to open the desired url. Add this to your code :

```
$("[data-role=footer] a").bind("click",function(){
    $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: they actually works, but when i click on link, it triggers my footer to show\hide aswell, so i'm trying to make links not trigger my footer to toggle without breaking ajax functions of jquery mobile